# how to add string with special character as json key?

Tags: javascript, json, special-characters

I want to add string with special character in JSON as KEY.For example "**Sam@123**"

Here is the code, that I am trying.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonObj={"sam":1,"rudolph":1,"js":1," ":12};
var key="samw@123";
alert("Add it.")
// Adding the key with Special Character in JSON
eval("jsonObj."+key+"=11")
alert("Added successfully.")

for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(jsonObj).length; i++){
alert("KEY#"+Object.keys(jsonObj)[i]);
}

</script>
```

I am getting following error at line 6 "`eval......`".

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Is there any other way to add special character in Json as KEY?

I am also not able to add

```
var key="samw-123";
```

for this I am getting error saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: you don't need to use eval to do this, see wizard's answer below

Comment: (a) You are not working with JSON here, only with JavaScript objects. (b) possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should work fine using such syntax instead:

```
eval("jsonObj['" + key + "'] = 11");
```

Actually, `eval` is not even required:

```
jsonObj[key] = 11;
```

Comment: Not only that, but using eval is bad. It opens you up to all kinds of security issues (what happens if key contains a quote character, for a start?).